How to scale an object with particles
I'm wanting to scale down an object that has a particle system, but the particles do not scale proportionally with the object, making the particles bigger in comparison when scaled down. Is there a setting in the particles that can fix this?



Scale the object you are rendering as a particle simultaneously. For example, if your particles were icospheres, then you would scale the particular icosphere as you scale your emitter.

I'm not sure if the particle system is using an object. Is there a way to find it?

If it is using one scroll down to the Render section, 'Render as' will say 'Object' and there will be an Object section below it. The Object Instance is the object it's using and you can scale it there (or scale the Object itself in Edit mode.) There doesn't seem to be a way of scaling if it's set to Halo as far as I'm aware but I'm not that familiar with the particle system.

I checked. It's not an object system, but a path system.
